# What would the following line of code do `eval("os.system('clear')", {})`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system

I've heard that this is disastrous. Why?

```
import os
eval("os.system('clear')", {})
```

#### EDIT :

Added `import os`. Think of the code as being a  few lines a larger program. All of the necessary imports are in place, etc....

Comment: Adding `import os` still doesn't do anything, because you're explicitly evaluating your expression in a global environment where the import didn't happen.

Comment: In fact, this was already explained to you in rassar's answer.

Answer (score 0):

That line doesn't do anything - `os.system('clear')` would clear the screen, but since `os` isn't imported it just errors.

The `{}` part of the line evaluates the code with no builtins, variables, or context, so even if you import `os` earlier it still errors:

```
>>> eval("os.system('clear')", {})
NameError: name 'os' is not defined
>>> import os
>>> eval("os.system('clear')", {})
NameError: name 'os' is not defined
```

`eval` itself is quite dangerous - don't run `eval` when you don't know what it will do, or on user input.

Comment: `os.system('clear')` doesn't clear the screen on all operating systems.

Comment: True, on Windows use `os.system('CLS')`

Comment: True...so IMO, the line of code is primarily an illustration of how `eval()` could do something dangerous — just presented in a way that couldn't do harm even if it were somehow successfully executed.